# How to preserve the value though it is not displayed in UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a field that is hidden in the ui under some conditions. When that field is hidden and not displayed in the UI, it gets updated to default values when the form is submitted.

```
@if (canManageAllEmployees)
{       
   <label title="Selecting this option will hide the employee's pay rate on all Profit Center pages." asp-for="PortalEmployee.HidePayRateIndicator" class="active"></label>
   <input asp-for="PortalEmployee.HidePayRateIndicator" />

}
else
{
    Model.PortalEmployee.HidePayRateIndicator = (bool)ViewBag.HidePayRate;
    <p> @Html.Raw(Model.PortalEmployee.HidePayRateIndicator)</p>
}
```

I have tried to set the Model value, but still the value is being false in the backend, though it is actually true.

I have one option for this, that is to set that field `Hidden`, but it will be still visible in the UI (through Inspecting tools in browser), and can still be updated.

So what could be an alternative for `HiddenFor`, or preserve the value without being able to update in any way from the browser or UI.

Comment: Cant you get the Rate value from the database. on the server? 
why do u want to send it to the UI then take it back ? 
why not take it from the database when submitting?

Comment: in my case it is a little bit complicated to check the condition in the backend and also I don't have access to the backend code, that updates the field.

Comment: though I recommend that even if its complicated you chunk it to small pieces ant tackle the complicity. however you can hash the value using a Sault key and send a hashed value to the hidden field and check if its the same value when submitted to the server

Comment: Could you store it in cookie for your requirement?